# how make parse in some ul?

Tags: php, parsing

```
<ul>
   <li>
   <a>name1</a>
   <div>
      <ul>
          <li>
             <a>name</a>
             <ul>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a>name</a>
             <ul>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a>name2</a>
   <div>
      <ul>
          <li>
             <a>name</a>
             <ul>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a>name</a>
             <ul>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a>name</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As we can se we hve some `<ul>`.
We would like use **[`PHP Simple HTML DOM`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)** for get array with data ul up.
We want use code:

```
foreach($html->find('li') as $li) {

}
```

But in this example we see all `li` on display:
http://prntscr.com/5390mf
http://prntscr.com/5390pj

But we dont know how get only parrent li:

```
1.
   <li>
   <a>name1</a>
   </li>
2.
   <li>
   <a>name2</a>
   </li>
```

And only than get childrens `ul` in parrents `li` and all children `li` in `li`.

*Tell me please how make it?*

*P.S.: if i do bad explain that I would like to receive, please write*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

```
foreach($html->find('li',0) as $line) {

}
```

**Second (*if we can add class to parrent `ul`*):**

```
foreach($html->find('ul.parrent_ul->li') as $line) {

}
```

***Enjoy!***

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('ul > li') as $li) {

}
```

Should get only the top level li's - the one's that are direct children of the ul elements

Comment: no, s you can see we get some `ul->li` in some `li`, and use you code we get all `ul->li` (not only parrent)